# gcc inline - operand type mismatch for 'cmp'

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, att

I get the following error:

> Assembler messages:
>   Error: operand type mismatch for `cmp'

The only cmp in my code is:

```
"cmpl %eax, $15\n\t"
```

I don't get what is wrong with that - I have a register and an immediate value which should be implicitly sign extended to 32bit.

Comment: When using att syntax (gcc's default), the constant needs to be the first param: `"cmpl $15, %eax\n\t"`.  Intel syntax puts the constant in the second parameter.  If all of your asm is intel format, use -masm=intel.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Even if I don't see why this is.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Official Intel ISA Reference](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf) *3.2 Instructions (A-L)*

> CMP EAX, *imm32*

Which means either in [Intel Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax)

```
cmp eax, 15D
```

or in [AT&T Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax):

```
cmpl $15, %eax
```

Just the opposite :)

---

`cmp` doesn't have a form that subtracts the reg/mem *from* an immediate.  Instead, use the opposite branch / cmov condition if you wanted to check something other than equality.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, but in my case the error was with

```
cmp $0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, %rdx
```

and the solution was to do

```
movq $0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, %rcx
```

first, and then

```
cmp %rcx, %rdx
```

(afaik, for bigger numbers cmp needs two registers, not const and register)

Comment: No, that's a separate problem.  The OP had their instruction backwards; CMP only supports `cmp $imm, reg/mem`, not `cmp reg/mem, $imm`.  In your case, it's that `cmp` (and all instructions other than `mov`) only support 32-bit sign-extended immediates, not 64-bit.